# Backbonejs: is passing a parent's element reference to a child view a good practice?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

giving a parent and a child view, I'd like 2 things:

- the child view should render itself on instantiation
- the child's render method should know the current parent's dom element

In practice, from the parent view, instead of this:

```
,add_bannerbox_view:function(model, collection, options){
    var bannerbox = new BannerBoxView({ model: model });
    this.bannerbox_views[model.cid] = bannerbox;
    this.bannerbox_container.append(bannerbox.el);
    bannerbox.render();
}
```

I'd like simply this;

```
    ,add_bannerbox_view:function(model, collection, options){
        //here, BannerBoxView is supposed to render itself from initialize() 
        this.bannerbox_views[model.cid] = new BannerBoxView({ model: model, parent:this.el });
    }
```

But I was wondering: is passing a parent's elem to the child a good practice? Or does it have some bad drawback?

Comment: Depending on what your trying to do, a better approach might be to use events to decouple the two, for example instead of your child view rendering something on it's parent element it would just trigger an event which the parent view would listen to and act accordingly.

Comment: ok yes I'm already using Backbone's Event as an event router for other things. In this case though, it's a parent creating a child. So If I'd use an event to try decoupling the 2, I guess I should pass the parent's element to the child as an event's callback argument, so just the same as above. My real problem here, maybe, is how to let the child know where to append itself to the dom.

Comment: Why not let the parent view append the child's view to the DOM? (`this.$('#someElement').append(this.bannerbox_views[model.cid].el);`)

Comment: that's exactly one of the things I'm trying to avoid because doing so, I need also to call the child's render() method, as it needs to know the parent element for some computations, so I can't call it before appending the element.

Anyway, my main question is: has this practice some serious drawbacks?

Comment: The main drawbacks I see is that your child view is more tightyly coupled with your parent's view and you might have a circular reference. Regarding rendering you view, although generally speaking the pattern is to render the view and then append it, I don't see why you can reverse that and do something like this (`this.$('#someElement').append(view.el); view.render();`).

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing (see code above), but I'd like views to be self responsible of adding themself to the dom. I think it should be part of the view's render() task itself. I'll think anyway more accurately of the circular reference issue, although, since I'd pass the parent's dom element and not the parent instance, maybe there could be no possibilities of real dangerous circular reference. What do you think about this?

Comment: I think if you are careful when removing the child's view to set it's `parent` reference to `null` it should be OK as far as the circular reference goes.

Answer (score 2):

Loose coupling is almost always preferable to tight coupling. The two best reasons I can think of are:

- **Reusable**. Can be used by anywhere in your app without worrying about dependencies.
- **Testable**. Can be tested independent of other components.

By requiring the child view to have a reference to the parent view, you are promoting tight coupling i.e. the child view becomes dependent on the parent view. This makes reusability extremely difficult, and if you're writing unit tests, you're going to have to instantiate or mock a parent class just so you can test the child. This is unnecessary and tedious.

If really what you're trying to do is have the child view automatically render, just extend the core `Backbone.View` and include a helper function that your parent views can call.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    renderChild: function(view, options) {
        var childView = new view(options);
        this.views[options.model.cid] = childView;
        this.$el.append(childView.el);
        childView.render();
    }
});
```

Then, you can define your parent views like so:

```
var ParentView = MyView.extend({
    add_bannerbox_view: function() {
        this.renderChild(BannerBoxView, {model: model});
    }
});
```

The helper function we made will let you instantiate, append and render your child views with a single line of code.

Comment: Ok, this is a good technique, thank you. But are you sure that passing the parent's $el (not parent itself) I'm coupling the 2? All I'm doing is simply passing a jquery object (or even simply the dom), not the view, just to tell the child where to append itself (since some of the child's properties need to know about the parent). As for the unit test, any view supposed to be a child will need to be appended somewhere, so you'll need some kind of parent anyway (not necessarily a view, just a simple dom element). How about this?

Comment: Technically, you are correct -- passing a reference to a DOM element is not the same as passing a reference to the parent view itself. However, this is making the assumption that it's okay for any view to access any part of the DOM tree -- something that I would argue goes against the tenets of modular design. I do feel that the DOM tree should be given the same modular consideration that we give to rest of our code. This is one of the things I love about shadow DOM in HTML5. It strongly encourages modular development within the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

I partially answer to myself. More than circular references (I'm passing only a dom element), drawbacks could arise for the self-appending functionality I'd like to use in child's render() method. The reason is possible memory leaks when having large number of views. There is a good explanation here:

http://ozkatz.github.io/avoiding-common-backbonejs-pitfalls.html

I should use `var container = document.createDocumentFragment()` in the parent view and then maybe pass container to the child view.

Also, following discussions above, and still not fully convinced of the various points (mine first :P) I'm using sort of bridge code. For now, I like doing this: I don't pass parent's dom element as a constructor argument. Instead, I pass it directly to the child's render(). The code is cleaned out to the bare bones:

```
//parent
var CustomBannersView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function(){
    this.groups_container = $('.groups-container');
    this.group_views = {};
    this.init();
    this.set_events();
}

,init:function(){
    //instantiate views without rendering for later use
    this.collection.each(function(model){
        this.group_views[model.cid] = new GroupView({ model:model, id:'group-' + model.cid });
    },this);
}

,render:function(){
    var temp_box = document.createDocumentFragment();

    //render views without dom refresh. Passing the box.
    _.each(this.group_views, function(groupview){ groupview.render(temp_box); });

    //add container
    this.groups_container.append(temp_box);
}

//dom events ----
,events:{
    'click .create-gcontainer-button': function(){
        this.collection.add(new Group());
    }
}

,set_events:function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection,'add',function(model, collection, options){           
        //render a single subview, passing the main container
        //no refresh problem here since it's a single view
        this.group_views[model.cid] = new GroupView({ model: model, id:'group-' + model.cid }).render(this.groups_container);
    });
}
});//end view


//child
var GroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'fieldset'
  ,className: 'group'

  ,initialize:function(){
    this.template = Handlebars.compile($('#group-container').html()); 
  }

  ,render:function(box){//box passed by parent
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    $(box).append(this.$el);
    //now I can set things based on dom parent, if needed
    return this;
  }
});
```